# Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient().ContactManager is null

Tags: api, sdk, lync, skype-for-business

In c# code, I call:

```
var lync = Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient();
```

That works. But two inner objects are null: 'ContactManager' and 'ConversationManager'.

I have used this program many times without any problem, this is the first time I see Lync API return null for the ContactManager.

What is going on?

The only difference I noticed is that the running lync client says: "Skype for Business and Exchange aren't making a connection right now". I didn't find any misconfiguration either in Exchange or Lync servers. I already rebooted both.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

The ContactManager and ConversationManager are both null when the LyncClient [State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.client.state_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt(v=office.14).aspx) in not in the [SignedIn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.clientstate_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt(v=office.14).aspx) state.   Which makes sense if the lync client is saying "Skype for Business and Exchange aren't making a connection right now".  i.e. it can't sign in at the moment.

You may like to see the sign in process [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn391637.aspx).

Comment: State was signed in

Comment: Then you have to program defensively to guard against seeing null's.  I find almost anything in the Lync API can be null at way time.  I don't think you can do anything about it.